# Getting incorrect MapViewport and coordinates for some searches

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I enter a place name in the search box 's-src' or 's-dest’, I get a location that is either in the arctic ocean or near the north pole.

This happens only for some places and not for others.

I get suggestions of place names from Google maps places autocomplete api.

```
var map;

function initMap(){
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: { lat: 22.8739881, lng: 81.8563971 },
    styles: mapConfig.mapStyles
});
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

var origin_input = document.getElementById('s-src');
var destination_input = document.getElementById('s-dest');

var origin_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(origin_input);
// origin_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

var destination_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destination_input);
// destination_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

origin_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function(){
    var place = origin_autocomplete.getPlace();
    if(!place.geometry){
        // statusMessage("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
        statusMessage("Please select location from suggestions. Thanks!");
        return;
    }
    expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);
});

destination_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function(){
    var place = destination_autocomplete.getPlace();
    if(!place.geometry){
        // statusMessage("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
        statusMessage("Please select location from suggestions. Thanks!");
        return;
    }
    expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);
});

var onChangeHanlder = function(){

    var origin = document.getElementById('s-src').value;
    var destination = document.getElementById('s-dest').value;

    if(origin == null || origin == "" || destination == null || destination == ""){
        statusMessage("Please Fill PickUp Location and Destination first. Thanks!")
    } else {
        calAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, origin, destination);
    }
};
// document.getElementById('s-src').addEventListener('change', onChangeHanlder);
// document.getElementById('s-dest').addEventListener('change', onChangeHanlder);
document.getElementById('s-search').addEventListener('click', onChangeHanlder);
}

function calAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, origin , destination){
var routeOptions = {
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
};
directionsService.route(routeOptions, function(response, status){
    if(status == 'OK'){
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        map.setZoom(11);
        document.getElementsByClassName('table-container')[0].style.display="block";

    } else {
        console.log('Directions request falied due to: ' + status);
    }
});
 }

function expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place){
if (place.geometry.viewport){
    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
} else {
    map.setCenter(place.geometry.viewport);
    map.setZoom(16);
}
}
```

**Live sample:**

[Map Sample](https://redcabz.in/map/map.html)

> Sample Inputs 1:

- Source: Hisar Bus Stand, Hisar, Haryana, India (Shows location in arctic ocean although its in india)
- Destination: Delhi (shows currect location)
- Click on search (shows correct path with correct origin location and destination location)

> Sample Input 2:

- Source: Hisar Bus Stand, Hisar, Haryana, India (Shows location in arctic ocean although its in india)
- Map will auto load
- Here i got 84.17594818267227, -164.01527 in console. Variable 'map' is declared global. You can get coordinates via map.getCenter().lng(); and map.getCenter().lat() in console.

Actual coordinates are lat 29.165751, lng 75.718513. got them correct in google maps and not from google maps api.

Want to know reason why this happens sometimes and not others. Also, how to counter this problem.

Comment: This needs much more detail. Can you make an example? Have you tried debugging the code - what coordinates are s-src and s-dest translated to?

Comment: @pekka Thanks. Check Update.

Comment: Can you try and debug the code to see what coordinates are returned for those locations exactly?

Comment: @pekka 84.17594818267227, -164.01527 . get these in console. Variable map is declared global . to get cordinates map.getCenter().lng(); and map.getCenter().lat();

Comment: Weird! I can see nothing obvious that could be causing this.

Comment: @pekka actual coordinates are lat 29.165751, lng 75.718513. got them correct in google maps and not from google maps api.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn’t seem to make any sense.

Comment: @pekka it makes some sense of course. Only we don't know how. :)

Comment: Sample inputs 1 & 2 look the same to me: "Hisar Bus Stand, Hisar, Haryana, India".  Is that a typo?

Comment: @geocodezip input1 have 2 values one for source and other for destination . Input 2 has only src location. these represents 2 scenarios to understand  the problem exactly

Answer (score 0):

The input "Hisar Bus Stand, Hisar, Haryana, India" returns a place object doen't have a `.viewport` property.  You have a typo in your `expandViewportToFitPlace` function.

```
function expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place) {
  if (place.geometry.viewport) {
    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
  } else {
    map.setCenter(place.geometry.viewport); // <-- this doesn't exist
    map.setZoom(16);
  }
}

function expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place) {
  if (place.geometry.viewport) {
    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
  } else {
    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
    map.setZoom(16);
  }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/tj9Ldvbj/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {
      lat: 22.8739881,
      lng: 81.8563971
    },
    // styles: mapConfig.mapStyles
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  var origin_input = document.getElementById('s-src');
  var destination_input = document.getElementById('s-dest');

  var origin_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(origin_input);
  // origin_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  var destination_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destination_input);
  // destination_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  origin_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = origin_autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      // statusMessage("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
      statusMessage("Please select location from suggestions. Thanks!");
      return;
    }
    expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);
  });

  destination_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = destination_autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      // statusMessage("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
      statusMessage("Please select location from suggestions. Thanks!");
      return;
    }
    expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);
  });

  var onChangeHanlder = function() {

    var origin = document.getElementById('s-src').value;
    var destination = document.getElementById('s-dest').value;

    if (origin == null || origin == "" || destination == null || destination == "") {
      statusMessage("Please Fill PickUp Location and Destination first. Thanks!")
    } else {
      calAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, origin, destination);
    }
  };
  // document.getElementById('s-src').addEventListener('change', onChangeHanlder);
  // document.getElementById('s-dest').addEventListener('change', onChangeHanlder);
  document.getElementById('s-search').addEventListener('click', onChangeHanlder);
}

function calAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, origin, destination) {
  var routeOptions = {
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  };
  directionsService.route(routeOptions, function(response, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      map.setZoom(11);
      // document.getElementsByClassName('table-container')[0].style.display = "block";

    } else {
      console.log('Directions request falied due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place) {
  if (place.geometry.viewport) {
    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
  } else {
    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
    map.setZoom(16);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<input id="s-src" value="Hisar Bus Stand, Hisar, Haryana, India" />
<input id="s-dest" value="Delhi" />
<input id="s-search" type="button" value="search" />
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: on google maps 'hisar bus stand' is visible but don't have viewport in geometry. how is that possible. As map is made from geometry , if a location does not have a viewport than how it is visible in google maps as the case here.

Comment: It has a `.location` property, just not a `.viewport` property

Comment: so this viewport is option here not a mandatory property for a geometry . Is that same applies to location property as well.

Comment: got my answer in docs https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PlaceGeometry